# HTML5 Seekbar/Media Controls without Media Source

Tags: html, media-player, seekbar

I would like to use the default seekbar used for audio and video tags in HTML5 without having any real media source attached. It looks like a media source is required. Anyone have an idea of how to get around this? Or maybe I'm better off creating my own?

Example of the type of seekbar I'm talking about at W3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

The reason I would like this is so that I can utilize the onseeking event for an animation. The seekbar will act like a timeline of sorts. It needs to be able to play, pause, and seek.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible if you could post your code so we can see.
Since I have done this a lot with other tags in HTML, maybe try:

```
<source src="#" type="#">
```

Usually this will overlook the src and type and it will still be there but there won't be any audio attached to it, but you could go back and change that later on.

I hope this helps, but I'm not really sure if I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok I'm updating the question with the code, and then I will try your solution.

Comment: Your solution just disables the seekbar

Comment: What specifically are you trying to use this for, and I don't think it will work then. There is probably another way I know of but you'll have to tell me specifically what the audio is being used for as its hard to tell from your question

Comment: There is no audio. I'm making a site with a canvas which I wish to have an interactive video. I want the video to be seekable, playable and pausable. There is no audio tied to the video as the "video" is actually a visualization of data. The seekbar duration will be something like 10,000 years...I don't want to go into too many details.